# como seleccionar datos de un datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

Tengo un datagrid y dentro de ese datagrid tengo 3 columnas, 2 de klas cuales recibe la información de una base datos y la tercera la digita el usuario dentro de esas columnas tengo varias filas, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se seleccione una fila esos datos me los muestre en 3 textbox los cuales 2 estan bloqueados y el tercero es donde se digita el valor, por el momento tengo que usted selecciona cualquier celda y me da el valor de esa celda en un textbox pero no necesito eso.

Answer (score 1):

```
var row = dvgDatos.CurrentRow;
```

esto te devuelve la fila seleccionada, después para volcar los datos en los textbox llamas de la fila la celda que necesitas.

```
var value = string.empty;
value = row["nombreDelaColumna"].toString();
//O Por indice 
var indexColumna = 0;//Índice de la columna en el datagrid
value = row[indexColumna].toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nos suscribimos al evento CellClick y en el metodo utilizaremos esto:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    textBox2.Text = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
    textBox3.Text = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;
}
```

Te aconsejo crees un metodo, algo que lo haga elegante ahora que sabemos como acceder a las celdas de la fila que has seleccionado.

Comment: y como hago para crear o llamar ese evento CellClick

Comment: así https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5iyElfFqj4

Comment: @Mr.Noone el problema es que yo estoy con un datagrid no con un datagridview y por ende los  Rows y los RowIndex me arroja error ahi como se puede solucionar (@fredyfx)

Answer (score 0):

Por que no cambias este datagrid por un dataGridView, es un control mejorado del clasico datagrid, y evitaras problemas como este.

Comment: De todas formas creo recordad que podrías acceder a la celda en un clasico datagrid como datagrid1.Columns(3).Text

Comment: por que por suerte mia en windows CE solo hay datagrid

Comment: como seria el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he hecho con Visual Basic .NET pero aquí te lo intentaré mostrar en C#

Utiliza el evento SelectedIndexChanged del GridView el cual se activará cada vez selecciones una fila o un registro.

Ahora, como primer paso obtén el número de fila y guárdalo en una variable llamada, por ejemplo, NumeroDeFila

```
    NumeroDeFila = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex
```

Posteriormente, obtén el valor de las celdas de esa fila y almacénalos en sus respectivos cuadros de texto.

```
    textBox1.Text = GridView1.Rows[NumeroDeFila].Cells[0].Text;
    textBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[NumeroDeFila].Cells[1].Text;
    textBox3.Text = GridView1.Rows[NumeroDeFila].Cells[2].Text;
```